# Плагин Wordpress social login. Авторизация на сайте через Facebook

Tags: wordpress, авторизация, facebook-api

На сайте используется плагин Wordpress Social Login 2.3.3

Facebook заблокировал учётную запись, на которой был зарегистрирован доступ к API для плагина.

Создали чётко по инструкции доступ к API Facebook с другой учётной записи, 
заменили "Application ID" и "Application Secret" в настройках плагина. 
При попытке входа через Facebook сервер отвечает:

> 500 Internal Server Error

Встречали ли вы такое поведение ?
Характерна ли ошибка для данного плагина ? 
Какие есть варианты для решения проблемы ?

Comment: В чём вопрос? Заблокировал, что дальше?